# Create custom dynamic with jpg extension for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a dynamic URL in WordPress to produce dynamic jpg images.
I have currently managed to achieve:
http://www.example.com/socialbar/48/

I want to convert it to
http://www.example.com/socialbar/48.jpg

I have tried with another extension (like .html) and it worked.. though jpg is being ignored and i get server's 404 (not wordpress post not found)

Current rewrite code

```html
add_rewrite_tag( '%socialbar%', '([^&]+)' );
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^socialbar/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?socialbar=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

Tried, '^socialbar/([^/]*).jpg' but it fails... Any idea?

Comment: Did you flush the rewrite?